# How to programmatically set weight for Button

Tags: android

I need to implement Dialog for my Android app through Java code, so I can't use XML.

I have root `LinearLayout` where I implement range seek bar, then I have another `LinearLayout` under root layout, with horizontal orientation, where I want to add two buttons in same row. So I need to set weight to 1, and width to `FILL_PARENT` and height to `WRAP_CONTENT`.

How I can do that with Java code?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
p.weight = 1;

rangeSeekBar.setLayoutParams(p);
```

I'm not sure which view you want to set the layout params on. I just assumed the rangeSeekbar to show an example. Change if you need.

When using the layout params always use the root's param type..

Ex. if you have a `View` you want to apply params to within a `RelativeLayout` use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`..

Answer (score 18):

You can pass it in as part of the LinearLayout.LayoutParams constructor:
Did you mean wrap_content?

```
LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                         LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
```

1.0f is the weight

Answer (score 0):

Is not using XML a requirement?  If not, you could always build your layout in XML and then use a `LayoutInflater` at run-time to build up your view hierarchy and pass that to `setView()` on your dialog.

For example:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_layout, null);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setView(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

an easier way:

```
public static void setLayoutWeight(View view , float weight)
{
    ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).weight = weight;
    view.requestLayout();
}
```